# How to connect and disconnect HM10 bluetooth module with Gnome GUI interface

Tags: gnome, 22.04, bluetooth

I have paired a HM10 Bluetooth module, that is connected to my Arduino to Ubuntu 22.04.  To do so I have to use `bluetoothctl` in the terminal.

When I open the Bluetooth settings in Gnome, the Bluetooth module appears there and updates when I disconnect or connect using `bluetoothctl` in the terminal, i.e. it shows 'connected/disconnected' and the connection slider moves left or right in the GUI.

But I can't click on this slider to get it to connect or disconnect like I can with other Bluetooth devices.

I would like to be able to connect or disconnect it from the GUI without having to use a terminal. Any help would be appreciated.